# Simulate USB mouse pointer input on Android phone?

Tags: android, mouse

Is it possible to simulate USB mouse movement and click inputs on an Android phone (or on the emulator), e.g. using USB debugging? I want to test if everything in my app also works when using a mouse, but I don't have a mouse I can connect to my Android phone.

Comment: You have probably seen the [scrcpy server-side application already](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/tree/master/app/src),  which you can use directly, or learn how to invoke events through it's source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with ADB by sending the events you want to the device. Here if you want to send a click event from the mouse, you can do this:

```
adb shell input mouse tap <x> <y>
```

Here's the docs for `adb shell input`:

> ```
> $ adb shell input --help
> Usage: input [<source>] [-d DISPLAY_ID] <command> [<arg>...]
>
> The sources are:
>     dpad
>     keyboard
>     mouse
>     touchpad
>     gamepad
>     touchnavigation
>     joystick
>     touchscreen
>     stylus
>     trackball
>
> -d: specify the display ID.
>     (Default: -1 for key event, 0 for motion event if not specified.)
> The commands and default sources are:
>     text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
>     keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
>     tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
>     swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
>     draganddrop <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
>     press (Default: trackball)
>     roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
>     event <DOWN|UP|MOVE> <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
> ```

KeyEvent codes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent?hl=en#constants

Comment: How to do this from an android app?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input tap 0 0")